# A bounded non Riemann integrable real function with set of discontinuity of empty interior

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, riemann-integration

Is possible to construct a bounded non Riemann integrable real function such that the set of discontinuity points has empty interior?
I know that if the set of discontinuity points is a null set then the answer is no. Every null set has empty interior but the converse is not true.

Comment: Do you mean for $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly. Say $K$ is a ["fat Cantor set"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set). So in particular $K$ is compact, has empty interior and positive Lebesgue measure.

Now define, for example, $$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
0,&(x \in K),
\\\sin(1 / (1+d(x,K))),&(x\notin K).
\end{cases}$$Then $f$ is discontinuous precisely on $K$ (and hence $f$ is not Riemann integrable, since $K$ is not a null set).

---

**Note** This is fairly stupid; as zhw points out we could simply let $f=\chi_K$ (that is, $f(t)=1$ for $t\in K$, $0$ for $t\notin K$). Replacing my stupidity with his non-stupidity seems like cheating, so I'll leave the above as it is.

Comment: Why not define $f =\chi_K?$

Comment: @zhw. Good question. No good answer available, sorry.

Comment: lol, my only complaint is I'm zhw., not zhu.

Comment: @zhw. Sorry....